# Exception in python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I'm very new to python so I have very simple doubt. Here is my code:

```
a=sri

try:
    print a
except Exception:
    print 'you have not put quotes for string'
else:
    print 'dont know what error it is'
```

How to write a manual exception/error handling for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for which you need to handle errors should be written in the `try` clause. The `except` clause is where you write how to handle the possible exceptions.

```
try:
    a=sri
    print a
except Exception:
    print 'you have not put quotes for string'
```

More on `try` statement from [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

> The try statement works as follows.
>
> - First, the try clause (the statement(s) between the try and except
>     keywords) is executed.
> - If no exception occurs, the except clause is
>     skipped and execution of the try statement is finished.
> - If an
>     exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the rest of the
>     clause is skipped. Then if its type matches the exception named after
>     the except keyword, the except clause is executed, and then execution
>     continues after the try statement.
> - If an exception occurs which does
>     not match the exception named in the except clause, it is passed on to
>     outer try statements; if no handler is found, it is an unhandled
>     exception and execution stops with a message as shown above.

Comment: please don't use blank exceptions. you can catch the example with `NameError`

Comment: Although using exception handling to catch errors you typed in your own code is kind of silly to begin with.